# CSS HTML parallax scrolling on 3 columns - desktop

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have 3 columns defined as left, middle and right. I am trying to make it work so these columns does not disappear from screen and the scrollbar can scroll until the end of each column height.

Here is some test code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  padding: 30px;
  margin: 0px;
}

.left {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 20%;
  float: left;
  height: 1000px;
  margin-right: 1%;
  border: 2px solid;
}

.middle {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 1%;
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 2000px;
}

.right {
  position: relative;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 29%;
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid;
  height: 1500px;
}

div:after {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'end';
  bottom: 10px;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="left">left</div>
<div class="middle">midle</div>
<div class="right">right</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried any javascript so far?

Comment: @Run_Script I have tried some but none is as close to what I need to get this working, Thanks

Comment: That's no problem, posting your attempt here will still help others to answer and point you in the right direction.

Comment: If you don't really care about IE, you can you `position: sticky`

Comment: @LukasJ. Aww, I wish we could :)